# Google Charts API CalendarChart

Tags: charts, google-api, google-visualization, google-calendar-api

I am using Google Charts API for my Data Visualisations. I would like to retrieve the date of the selected day on the Chart.

What I retrieve is quite strange.. I am using a selectHandler on the chart as recommended by documentation.

```
  function selectHandler() {

    console.log(chart.getSelection()[0]);

  }

  google.visualization.events.addListener(chart, 'select', selectHandler);
```

On clicking following date, I am reading following output on console:

22/04/2020       :        1587513600000

19/06/2020       :        1592524800000

What kind of date format is this? 
Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this is the date represented as the number of milliseconds since the Unix Epoch.
it is the same value as returned by the `getTime()` [method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getTime) on a date object.

you can pass the value received from the selection to the date constructor to get the date...

```
var selection = chart.getSelection();
if (selection.length > 0) {
  var selectedDate = new Date(selection[0].date);
}
```

see following working snippet...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  packages: ['calendar']
}).then(function () {
  var dataTable = new google.visualization.DataTable();
  dataTable.addColumn({ type: 'date', id: 'Date' });
  dataTable.addColumn({ type: 'number', id: 'Won/Loss' });
  dataTable.addRows([
    [ new Date(2012, 3, 13), 37032 ],
    [ new Date(2012, 3, 14), 38024 ],
    [ new Date(2012, 3, 15), 38024 ],
    [ new Date(2012, 3, 16), 38108 ],
    [ new Date(2012, 3, 17), 38229 ],
    [ new Date(2013, 9, 4), 38177 ],
    [ new Date(2013, 9, 5), 38705 ],
    [ new Date(2013, 9, 12), 38210 ],
    [ new Date(2013, 9, 13), 38029 ],
    [ new Date(2013, 9, 19), 38823 ],
    [ new Date(2013, 9, 23), 38345 ],
    [ new Date(2013, 9, 24), 38436 ],
    [ new Date(2013, 9, 30), 38447 ]
  ]);

  var chart = new google.visualization.Calendar(document.getElementById('calendar_basic'));

  var options = {
   title: "Red Sox Attendance",
   height: 350,
  };

  function selectHandler() {
    var selection = chart.getSelection();
    if (selection.length > 0) {
      var selectedDate = new Date(selection[0].date);
      console.log(selectedDate);
    }
  }

  google.visualization.events.addListener(chart, 'select', selectHandler);

  chart.draw(dataTable, options);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="calendar_basic"></div>
```

note: you should check the length of the selection before accessing the contents.
the select event is also called when a date is un-selected.
in this case the selection array will be empty...

Comment: Thanks! I have it up and running.. Take care!